# Can't set an AND in my WHERE from my EVENT query MySQL

Tags: mysql

This is weird because it works, just to the first requirement of my where which is the "date <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)" and not allowing another requirement with the sentence "AND".

```
CREATE EVENT
mysitioMaintance
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 24 DAY_HOUR
STARTS '00:00'
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO BEGIN
DELETE FROM `usuario` WHERE date <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
AND
state LIKE '0' 
END;
```

Comment: `DO BEGIN`, but where is `END`?

Comment: What's your delimiter? And why are you using `LIKE` without a `%`?

Comment: becouse it works... the selft delet sentence.

Comment: the "END" i believe is not needed but it still not working.

Comment: Not working means what exactly?\

Comment: that is not a succesfull query. It has some error.

Comment: any real help pls?